# How is ThreatExpert Memory Scanner different from the likes of MalwareBytes, etc?

Tags: anti-malware

I understand that ThreatExpert Memory Scanner scans memory objects however is this not the same as what MalwareBytes does or any other anti-malware?

http://www.threatexpert.com/memoryscanner.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the release date (March 1, 2008.) this appears to be an abandoned project

The biggest difference between any malware scanner is the dat files (signatures) it uses to detect the malware. No one scanner finds everything, that is why I use at least 3 different scanners on an infected machine,

"by using advanced techniques it is able to detect traces of these threats"

Sounds like a sales pitch, doesn't really tell us anything

Comment: Thanks. Not that I intend to start a thread on what each user uses but would you mind sharing the scanners you use? I know the most populates ones seem to be MalwareBytes, HitmanPro, ThreatFire, SuperAntiSpyWare, WebRoot, etc but am interested to know what the professionals use.

Comment: Several different Boot AV discs, by Kaspersky, Microsoft System Sweeper, these remove the more difficult infections. once I clean offline using a boot cd, then I use mbam and SAS to clean up the leftovers. Some like Norton Power Eraser

Answer (score 1):

As @Moab says, ThreatExpert seems to be abandonware.  But if you're really asking, "What's the difference between A/V (Kaspersky, Sophos, Symantec, etc.) and Malwarebytes, the answer is that Malwarebytes has a focus on zero day malware whereas the A/V products protect against a very wide range of things, including much older attacks that are less prevalent today.  In this way, they can be viewed as complimentary products - you can run both.

Answer (score 0):

@Scott Wilson, what you will find is that as Malwarebytes, A/V and other A/M applications grew over the last *2-3 years to the extent that they are no longer compatible running alongside each other; meaning you will need to remove Malwarebytes and most other A/M applications before installing an A/V application.*

Unfortunately; Full Scans, Database Virus Definitions and network monitoring over the range of A/V applications have been conflicting with A/M applications. (Malwarebytes specifically.) 
It kind of gets like trying to force 2 people through a narrow door, this means look into the A/V and A/M applications and their compatibility before buying.

(A/V = Kaspersky, Sophos, Symantec, AVG, ect.. A/M = Malwarebytes, Spybot Search & Destroy, ect -- Also Comodo to an extent)

Currently, as it looks for most A/V applications and A/M applications; dimming are the days that they will be able to run along one side and the other. (Which honestly really sucks in my opinion..)

In the case of 'ThreatExpert Memory Scanner' and MalwareBytes however from the outset, they seem to be compatible; they do not provide the same functions nor do they provide live protection from threats; so the chances are they would not be conflicting.

Hopefully though this clears the air on A/V and A/M! (And makes sense too!)